# Save number of numy arrays as one matrix in npy

Tags: numpy

I have result of some function as numpy of 8*1024. I need to save large number of such results in npy as one matrix. One way I could do is:

```
result []
for input in range(inputs):    
    arr = computer (input) # arr = 8*1024
    result.append(arr)
# After loop completes, save results 
np.save('result.npy', result)
```

If I append all results in "result", it is on RAM so RAM goes to 100% in use. I need to save 'arr' in npy as it gets computed.
Later, in order to do further processing, I load npy as given below, here I need to load results in random pattern:

```
result_load = np.load ('result.npy, mmap_mode='r)
x = results[i] # i is some arbitrary random index
final_result = algo_n(x)
```

Here, due to directly accessing from disk, I don't need too much RAM, however, in first part I can't find any way to save all array with out using too much RAM.

Note: I have to do both processing separately as I have to try multiple algos on "x"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-create a memory mapped file with [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) and write the arrays into slices of the memmap - similar to the approach you already use for loading parts of the file:

```
import numpy as np

def computer(i):
    return np.ones((8, 1024)) * i

inputs = 2

result = np.memmap('result.bin', mode='w+', shape=(inputs, 8, 1024))
for i in range(inputs):    
    arr = computer (i) # arr = 8*1024
    result[i] = arr
del result  # close the file
```

Note that `'result.bin'` is a raw binary file that `np.load` cannot open. You need to use `np.memmap` for loading (you need to specify the shape of the array):

```
result_load = np.memmap('result.bin', mode='r', shape=(inputs, 8, 1024))
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response.

If have 'result1.bin' and 'result2.bin', Can I memory map both together so that I can read any instance of result1 and result2. 
Let result1.bin has the matrix (n1, 8,1024) and results2.bin has the matrix (n2, 8,1024), where n1 and n2 are the numbers of instances. Now, I need to select random instances from either of both results.

Comment: I don't think you can map multiple files together. However, a relatively easy solution would be to make a separate script that combines them into a single (n1+n2, 8, 1024) file.